# PayPal integration with OpenShift Online -- SSL IPN Issue

Tags: openshift, paypal-ipn

I built an app on OpenShift Online and now I'm trying to integrate with PayPal. I'm running into SSL cURL errors that I don't know how to address. I've looked through SO, OpenShift Online, PayPal and elsewhere but can't get this issue worked through.

Background:

- PHP-based app running on OpenShift Online v2
- Setup as
  https://*******.rhcloud.com/test/test_IPN.php --- so I can use their
  *.rhcloud.com wildcard certificate
- Using PayPal "Buy Now" button with PayPal Payments Standard, testing in their sandbox
- Using IPN sample code found at
  https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

Here is the portion of the code that seems to be at the root of my problem:

```
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.

//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
```

Problem:

[1] using code "as is" (lines 79-80 commented out) throws curl error: "SSL connect error"

[2] using lines 79-80 uncommented out (and cacert.pem placed in same dir as php script) throws curl error: "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"

It's likely I'm missing something simple here. Any help getting this to work properly on OpenShift Online is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Force the use of TLS 1.2

Commenting out lines 79-80 and adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); // Force TLS 1.2
```

did the trick for me. Hope this helps someone else.

P.S. The need for TLS 1.2 came from this PayPal article https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

This line is pretty suspect:

```
$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
```

Basically you would end up with something like $cert equaling /home/path./cacert.pem, which I am pretty sure is not what you want, and why you are getting the ssl error, it can't find the certificate.
That could be corrected to:

```
$cert = __DIR__ . "/cacert.pem";
```

It also might be better to store the cacert.pem in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR and reference it as such:

```
$cert = getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR")."cacert.pem";
```

And make sure that the permissions on the cacert.pem are at least 0644

```
chmod 0644 $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/cacert.pem
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. It looks like I don't need the cacert.pem file after all. PayPal stepped up security on their sandbox testing environment by requiring TLS 1.2 in July, 2016. Unfortunately, their docs and recommended sample PHP IPN code don't seem reflect the change yet.